# How to make the selectInput choices in Shiny extend beyond the well panel or otherwise make them more viewable by the user?

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, selectinput

In running the example code posted at the bottom, the viewing of the `selectInput()` choices are obscured by the bottom edge of the `wellPanel()`. You can see an example of this obfuscation in the below image. The user has to fiddle with the mouse wheel to view all of the input choices. In the full code this example is deployed in, the problem is worse than in this example in getting the right-most `selectInput()` choices to render for the user's viewing. Is there a way to get the choices to extend below the `wellPanel()`, or to otherwise address this quirk?

The `wellPanel()` needs to scroll along the x-axis the way it currently does, and I don't want a huge `wellPanel()` that far exceeds the size of the `selectInput()` boxes when they are dormant. The below formats nicely when the `selectInput()` boxes are dormant; there are no huge empty margins. The only problem is when the user tries viewing and selecting the choices.

[image]

Example code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(), br(),
  wellPanel(
    style = "overflow-x: scroll",
    splitLayout(
      column(
        12,
        selectInput("i1", "I1", c("Boy","Cat","Dog","Rat","Bat"))
      ),
      column(
        12,
        selectInput("i2", "I2", c("Boy","Cat","Dog","Rat","Bat"))
      ),
      column(
        12,
        selectInput("i3", "I3", c("Boy","Cat","Dog","Rat","Bat"))
      ),
      cellWidths = "40%"
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice:

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(".selectize-dropdown {position: unset;}"))
  ),
  br(), br(),
  wellPanel(
    style = "overflow-x: hidden",
    splitLayout(
      ......
```